# Numeric String extraction

Tags: excel

I am trying to extract a sub-string from a string. The strings are currently in an excel column, row by row and are like this:

`ABC 54 SOMETHING 11165 POP 1234567890
SOMETHING ABC/W 05/1234500022385
SomethingW1234500006840Abc05 d 13/1/15`

What I want is to extract any 5 or 13-digit number from each row string.

I have come up with this algorithm for the job:

1) Enter line
2) Scan string
3) If numeric/integer found, check length from start to end of numeric string
4) If length = 5 or if length = 13, output only numeric string to next column
5) Enter new line...
6) Continue 1 - 5 Till the data set is exhausted

Is there a function in excel that can do this?

P.S: I am open to learn any language/tool that can get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier than you are making it. If I were you, I'd update that question to give unambiguous pairs of inputs and desired outputs. And I would take a good hard look at the accepted answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops) possibly similar question as it looks like it could be useful. Undoubtedly, someone will come up with a more beautiful regex for you, but [here](https://regex101.com/r/qR4zT6/1) is an idea that might work..